# $(document).on('change', function(){}) vs $('.class-name').on('change', function(){})

Tags: jquery

When implementing a new Jquery function to execute events, which is the best selector to choose as a parent element selector? Which will be the most effective from below code fraction?

```
$(document).on('change', `div[id^="parameter_${fieldId}"]`, function() {
      console.log("ID of parameter chaged element: " + fieldId);
});
```

vs

```
$('.other-parameters').on('change', `div[id^="parameter_${fieldId}"]`, function() {
      console.log("ID of parameter chaged element: " + fieldId);
});
```

> **div[id^="parameter_${fieldId}** is genereated dynamically and **.other-parameter** class is a static class in parent element for *div[id^="parameter_${fieldId}*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, it is fastest to use an ID as a selector (a la `getElementById` in vanilla JS) if at all possible. Second-best for performance is the contextual syntax, like your latter example, which will limit the starting scope that jQuery needs to crawl to find selector matches.

I believe the fastest / most performant way would be:

```
$(`div#parameter_${fieldId}`).on('change', function() {
  ...
});
```

Followed by:

```
$('#other-parameters').on('change', `div#parameter_${fieldId}`, function() {
  ...
});
```

You will always get the fastest performance if you start with an ID (and as long as it is unique on the page.)

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. But, the function can not access the selector without the parent element. Because div#parameter_${fieldId} is generated dynamically. Therefore defining the parent element is required.

Comment: @MD40 Without seeing your code, I can't really comment further.  Performance is based on how many DOM elements your code must crawl to find the selector.  Standard practice is to use IDs where performance is a requirement.  You can easily target a shared parent with an ID.  The "on" will watch for new elements.